# Installing Linux without UEFI

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

I have a old [Dell Dimension 8400](http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-dimension-8400-series-for-home/specs/) whose motherboard does not have UEFI.  I upgraded the RAM to 2 GB.  Also, it does not have a CD drive anymore, so the only way to install an OS is through a flash drive.  Most Linux installer programs create a EFI folder which my computer cannot boot.  Are there any programs that can create a bootable drive without using UEFI?

Comment: Most Linux installers should configure UEFI boot for UEFI systems and BIOS boot for BIOS systems.

Comment: @garethTheRed I'm using the installer on a Windows 7 computer (which has UEFI) since my Dimension's XP install is corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this has to do with UEFI, as I've never heard of any Linux distro that won't still boot via BIOS.

Just download an ISO image of the distro you wish to install, and use something like [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to "burn" it to a USB flash drive.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason Rufus seems to have more options than other installer programs. I just selected the BIOS option and now I have Lubuntu on my computer!

Comment: this is an option, too. I do not want GUI tools if I can have full control on the cli: dd is the tool of choice. Command line is ist. Sure there is plenty of nice stuff like Ventoy to play around with ...

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

There is a simple way to install Ubuntu w/o EFI:

After you dd the ISO file on the stick there are 2 partitions on your usb stick. One of them is EFI / UEFI.

Insert the stick in your operational Linux machine and invoke fdisk (sudo required).

Lets assume your stick is /dev/sdf. You see sdf1 linux and sdf2 EFI on the stick.

Use fdisk to delete partiton 2 on /dev/sdf. "Write" and end fdisk. Remove USB-stick.

Now use the stick for your installation machine.

The nuisance is gone! No more questions for a missing UEFI partition on the target disk. Smooth and simple installation.

No more additional problems and complications by UEFI!!

Answer (score 1):

Be aware which software you use to create the USB Boot Disk!

I first created the USB Boot Disk with Ubuntu's ["Startup Disc Creator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_Disk_Creator). In this case, my computer couldn't boot the Non-UEFI version.
Booting the Non-UEFI version created by [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) worked flawlessly.

Note: Make sure that you select the Non-UEFI Version in your BIOS when defining the boot priority.